# MongoDB uses wrong index, even after clearing the query plan cache

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I have the following command:

```
db.mycol.find({sourceId:ObjectId("596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF"),myFlag:false}).count()
```

It was taking a lot of time.
So I decided to add an index `{ "sourceId" : -1, "myFlag" : -1 }`

MongoDB still kept taking the same time.

When I ran `explain()` on the find command, I noticed that mongoDB still kept using my old indexes.

```
db.mycol.find({sourceId:ObjectId("596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF"),myFlag:false}).explain(true)
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "mydb.mycol",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "sourceId" : {
                        "$eq" : ObjectId("596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "myFlag" : {
                        "$eq" : false
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "myFlag" : {
                    "$eq" : false
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "sourceId" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "sourceId_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "sourceId" : [
                        "[ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF'), ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF')]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "sourceId" : {
                        "$eq" : ObjectId("596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF")
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "myFlag" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "myFlag_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "myFlag" : [
                            "[false, false]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "myFlag" : {
                        "$eq" : false
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "sourceId" : -1,
                        "timestamp" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "sourceId_-1_timestamp_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "sourceId" : [
                            "[ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF'), ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF')]"
                        ],
                        "timestamp" : [
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "myFlag" : {
                        "$eq" : false
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "sourceId" : -1,
                        "timestamp" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "sourceId_-1_timestamp_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "sourceId" : [
                            "[ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF'), ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF')]"
                        ],
                        "timestamp" : [
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "sourceId" : -1,
                        "myFlag" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "sourceId_-1_myFlag_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "sourceId" : [
                            "[ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF'), ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF')]"
                        ],
                        "myFlag" : [
                            "[false, false]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 2074,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 33936,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 2074,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 2074,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "myFlag" : {
                    "$eq" : false
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 2074,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 31710,
            "works" : 2075,
            "advanced" : 2074,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 1554,
            "restoreState" : 1554,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 2074,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 2074,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 2075,
                "advanced" : 2074,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 1554,
                "restoreState" : 1554,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "sourceId" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "sourceId_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "sourceId" : [
                        "[ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF'), ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF')]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 2074,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [
            {
                "nReturned" : 0,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1630,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 101,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 101,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "sourceId" : {
                            "$eq" : ObjectId("596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF")
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 0,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1630,
                    "works" : 101,
                    "advanced" : 0,
                    "needTime" : 101,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 1554,
                    "restoreState" : 1554,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 101,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 101,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 101,
                        "advanced" : 101,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 1554,
                        "restoreState" : 1554,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "myFlag" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "myFlag_-1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "myFlag" : [
                                "[false, false]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 101,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 101,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 101,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 101,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "myFlag" : {
                            "$eq" : false
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 101,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 101,
                    "advanced" : 101,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 1554,
                    "restoreState" : 1554,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 101,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 101,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 101,
                        "advanced" : 101,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 1554,
                        "restoreState" : 1554,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "sourceId" : -1,
                            "timestamp" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "sourceId_-1_timestamp_-1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "sourceId" : [
                                "[ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF'), ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF')]"
                            ],
                            "timestamp" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 101,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 101,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 101,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 101,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "myFlag" : {
                            "$eq" : false
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 101,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                    "works" : 101,
                    "advanced" : 101,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 1554,
                    "restoreState" : 1554,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 101,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 101,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 101,
                        "advanced" : 101,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 1554,
                        "restoreState" : 1554,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "sourceId" : -1,
                            "timestamp" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "sourceId_-1_timestamp_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "sourceId" : [
                                "[ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF'), ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF')]"
                            ],
                            "timestamp" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 101,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 101,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 101,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 101,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "nReturned" : 101,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 101,
                    "advanced" : 101,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 1554,
                    "restoreState" : 1554,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 101,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 101,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 101,
                        "advanced" : 101,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 1554,
                        "restoreState" : 1554,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "sourceId" : -1,
                            "myFlag" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "sourceId_-1_myFlag_-1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "sourceId" : [
                                "[ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF'), ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF')]"
                            ],
                            "myFlag" : [
                                "[false, false]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 101,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 101,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 101,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 101,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "myFlag" : {
                            "$eq" : false
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 101,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 101,
                    "advanced" : 101,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 88,
                    "restoreState" : 88,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 101,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 101,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 101,
                        "advanced" : 101,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 88,
                        "restoreState" : 88,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "sourceId" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "sourceId_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "sourceId" : [
                                "[ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF'), ObjectId('596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF')]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 101,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "gdm3d",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.15",
        "gitVersion" : "e11e3c1b9c9ce3f7b4a79493e16f5e4504e01140"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

For some reason, it rejects the plan to use `sourceId_-1_myFlag_-1` and goes with `sourceId_1` and then filters `myFlag` document by document.

When I forced it to use the index, it returned the result immediately!

```
db.mycol.find({sourceId:ObjectId("596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF"),myFlag:false}).hint("sourceId_-1_myFlag_-1").count()
```

I read that periodically mongoDB runs all the plans and checks which one is faster, then uses that one in future.
I even tried restarting the mongodb, clearing query plan cache, restarting the computer. For some `sourceId`s with very less data, it did use the correct index automatically (I checked the index usage) but then it again started using the old ones.

I don't want to force it to use the index. How do I make sure it automatically does that?

**Update:**
It started using the correct one after some time. Atleast thats what the `indexStats` says.
However, the command still takes time, and when i give it `hint`, it gives output immediately.

Comment: Get rid of that `sourceId_1` index. You don't need it as long as you have that `sourceId_-1_myFlag_-1`. The second choice is to turn that latter index around. `myFlag_1_sourceId_1` (direction of index don't matter).

Comment: @JJussi, can you please see the "update" part of the question and let me know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584233/mongodb-takes-different-time-for-with-and-without-hint