# MongoDB takes different time for with and without hint

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I know, I know, `hint` forces MongoDB to use a specific index.

**I have two queries:**

```
db.mycol.find({sourceId:ObjectId("596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF"),myFlag:false}).count()

db.mycol.find({sourceId:ObjectId("596bac5a6f473e1a042bFFFF"),myFlag:false}).hint("sourceId_-1_myFlag_-1").count()
```

Both of these commands take different time:

**Without hint:** 4-6 seconds
**With hint :** 0-1 second

However, both of the commands are using the same index:
`{ "sourceId" : -1, "myFlag" : -1 }`

When I execute `db.mycol.aggregate( { $indexStats: { } } )`,
I can see the `accesses.ops` count increases for the same index.

Even `explain` shows me the same index will be used!

Comment: If you repeat those two queries (multiple times), do they still take the same amount of time?

Comment: Yes, the one without `hint` keeps taking same or almost same time